# How to create a method with a generic return type in dart

Tags: generics, dart, typedef

I have a enum defined like this

```
enum PropertyType { apartment, villa, plot }
enum PossesionType { readyToMove, underConstruction }
```

I am trying to create a generic method,which returns me the right enum when given a string as input

```
class Property<T> {
 T getGenericType(String text) {
    switch (text) {
      case 'Ready to move':
        return PossesionType.readyToMove;
        break;
      case 'Apartment':
        return PropertyType.apartment;
        break;
      ....
      ....
      ....  
      default:
        return PossesionType.readyToMove;
 }   
}
```

I understand this will throw an error since it expects a return type of T, to get this working without generics I need to write two different functions with a different return type but both functions will basically do the same thing.

```
  PropertyType getSelectedProperty(String text) {
    switch (text) {
      case 'Apartment':
        return PropertyType.apartment;
        break;
      case 'Villa':
        return PropertyType.villa;
        break;
      case 'Plot':
        return PropertyType.plot;
        break;
      default:
        return PropertyType.apartment;
    }
  }

  PossesionType getSelectedPossession(String text) {
    switch (text) {
      case 'Ready to move':
        return PossesionType.readyToMove;
        break;
      case 'Under Construction':
        return PossesionType.underConstruction;
        break;
      default:
        return PossesionType.readyToMove;
    }
  }
```

I am new to generics so can someone help me understand how can I achieve this.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Seems odd that you have a need to convert a `String` to an enum. This would not be an appropriate place to use generics either it seems.

Comment: oh okay actually I have a set of radio buttons in the UI and I am getting a String value from the backend where I need to show one of the radio button to be selected based on the string returned from backend.

Comment: This makes no sense for generics.  With static typing, the caller needs to know *in advance* what return type to expect.  If you want the possibility to return multiple types, you'd have to return a `dynamic` or `Object` and require that callers perform runtime checks to tell what's returned.

Comment: Also, these options don't sound appropriate for a single set of radio buttons because they're not all mutually exclusive.  The `PropertyType` and `PossesionType` values seem like they should be independent, and therefore it'd more appropriate to use two sets of radio buttons (or one set of radio buttons and one checkbox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write two different functions.

When calling a generic function, like `T parseProperty<T>(String text) { ... }`, you need to know which type to return *at compile time*. Otherwise you'll have to pass `dynamic` as type argument.

As you have also noticed, simply abstracting over the return type makes it hard to implement the function. You'll have to put `as T` on every return expression, because there is no way to invent an object of an unknown type.

All in all, you are better off having either two functions, if you know the type at compile-time, or having one function returning `Object` if you don't.